# UIButton's setTitleShadowOffset is deprecated

Tags: ios, uibutton, customization

I am using `UIButton`'s appearance proxy to customize all `UIButtons` in my application. Everything is working very well - I can set custom image, text color and shadow color. Only one thing is bugging me. To set shadow offset, I've used this piece of code:

```
[[UIButton appearance] setTitleShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(1, 1)];
```

And it's working. But the documentation says that `setTitleShadowOffset:` is deprecated, and instead we should use the `shadowOffset` property of the titleLabel. I've tried it like this:

```
[[[UIButton appearance] titleLabel] setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake (1.0, 1.0)];
```

but it's not working. Can I set shadow offset without using a deprecated method?

Comment: I thought it was the oposite: UIButton's label related methods are deprecated, and you should instead modify the title label's properties directly (e.g. setFont: ). Furthermore, this kind of deprecation is supposed to be around since long before iOS 5...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
[[UILabel appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UIButton class], nil]
    setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(1.0, 1.0)];
```

(`[[UILabel appearance]
        setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(1.0, 1.0)];` should also work but is probably overkill as it will affect all `UILabels`, not just the ones contained in `UIButtons`.)